# Are values rounded when only printed?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

Sorry for the bad question, but I have a problem with the rounding of certain variables, I think.

In my C application, I have to compute the energy spent and the remaining one of a sensor node. This is computed every 10 seconds like this:

```
cycle_energy = (some long mathematical computation)

energy_spent += cycle_energy;
remaining_energy -= cycle_energy;
```

At the beginning of the application the two quantities are initialized at:

```
static float energy_spent = 0;
static float remaining_energy = 1000000;
```

Then every 10 seconds the two values are printed. Since the gcc I use supports floats for computations but not for printing, I convert the two quantities into unsigned long.

```
printf("Energy spent: %lu \n", (uint32_t) energy_spent);
printf("Remaining energy: %lu \n", (uint32_t) remaining_energy);
```

The problem is that, at the end of the application, the quantity `1000000 - energy_spent` should be equal to `remaining_energy` from the way they are computed.

However this is not true in my application. The quantities `1000000 - energy_spent` and `remaining_energy` are very similar at the beginning, but their difference increase with time.

For example, at the end of the application, in a case `energy_spent = 207223` and `remaining_energy = 792093`, in another `energy_spent = 215695` and `remaining_energy = 783828`.

I think the only problem lies when I print the values, however I though that when values are only printed they are not rounded.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Suffix with `.f` for `float` e.g. `static float remaining_energy = 1000000.f;`

Comment: @DavidRF why should he?

Comment: @DavidRF Do you mean that my variable `remaining_energy` is initialized as integer?

Comment: @rasen %f does not work with msp430 gcc, since I need to convert them to unsigned integers.

Comment: You can print floats with printf's %f flag.
When you print values with convertion to uint32_t, the value is not rounded but truncated.

Comment: @ouah, floating point literal without suffix defines double

Comment: @aliants, no, as double

Comment: @DavidRF There is no `double` involved in `static float remaining_energy = 1000000;`. It initializes `remaining_energy` to the conversion to `float` of the `int` (or larger integer type) value `1000000`. I do not see either what writing `1000000.f` is supposed to bring. Any moderately sane compiler would generate the same code and/or data for the two (note that 1000000 = 5^6* 2^6 = 15625 * 2^6 is representable exactly as an IEEE 754 single-precision number).

Comment: What is a typical value for `cycle_energy`?

Comment: @chux a typical value for `cycle_energy` can be 15,170047211 (from the computation)

Comment: Although you have all ready selected an answer, I was exploring another line-of-thought.  Dead-end.  BTW: using `remaining_energy = total_energy - energy_spent;` will keep your sum to 1000000, but you'll still experience float drift with `energy_spent`.  Recommend using `double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in float type itself. It has not enought significant bits to store your value as is.

See this theme: [Number of significant digits for a floating point type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815179/number-of-significant-digits-for-a-floating-point-type).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It means that, for my float variable equal to 1000000, I can have an error in storing up to 0.0001%, that means up to 1 for every cycle. This is the reason of the float drift, is it right?

Answer (score 1):

You are simply expiriencing float drift - this is definitly not unusal!

The canonical way is to

```
static float energy_spent = 0;
static float total_energy = 1000000;
remaining_energy = 1000000;
```

and then

```
energy_spent += cycle_energy;
remaining_energy = total_energy - energy_spent;
```

Comment: What's the reason of float drift? I have found nothing on the web. Thanks.

Comment: @aliants, The reason is that float has not significant bits to store value and some calculation error is present. With many calculations these errors sums up.

Comment: If you assimilate rounding errors to a white noise with some distribution for example, uniform in [-ulp/2,ulp/2] for an elementary operation, what you are doing with += noise is cumulating those errors which lead you to the integral of a white noise, a kind of Brownian noise. The noise of the two operations += and -= are mostly independant, hence the drift (you can predict the variance of the drift, it probably increases like the square root of time)