# Am I doing double to float conversion here

Tags: c++

```
const double dBLEPTable_8_BLKHAR[4096] = {
  0.00000000000000000000000000000000,
  -0.00000000239150987901837200000000,
  -0.00000000956897738824125100000000,
  -0.00000002153888378764179400000000,
  -0.00000003830892270073604800000000,
  -0.00000005988800189093979000000000,
  -0.00000008628624126316708500000000,
  -0.00000011751498329992671000000000,
  -0.00000015358678995269770000000000,
  -0.00000019451544774895524000000000,
  -0.00000024031597312124120000000000,
  -0.00000029100459975062165000000000
}
```

If I change the double above to float, am I doing incurring conversion cpu cycles when I perform operations on the array contents? Or is the "conversion" sorted out during compile time?

Say, `dBLEPTable_8_BLKHAR[1] + dBLEPTable_8_BLKHAR[2]` , something simple like this?

On a related note, how many trailing decimal places should a float be able to store?

This is c++.

Comment: The conversion happens at compile time. Also, [floats store about 6 digits of precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815179/number-of-significant-digits-for-a-floating-point-type).

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, so we need to know which

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const double dBLEPTable_8_BLKHAR[4096] = {
```

If you change the `double` in that line to `float`, then one of two things will happen:

1. At compile time, the compiler will convert the numbers `-0.00000000239150987901837200000000` to the `float` that best represents them, and will then store that data directly into the array.
2. At runtime, during the program initialization (before `main()` is called!) the runtime that the compiler generated will fill that array with data of type `float`.

Either way, once you get to `main()` and to code that you've written, all of that data will be stored as `float` variables.

Comment: What if the array is in a local function?

Comment: @NeilKirk: An optimizing compiler will probably do the same thing, because the variable is `const` and therefore overwriting it is undefined behavior, so the compiler can avoid per-call initialization and just refer to an area of the pre-initialized data segment.  Particularly if it can prove that addresses of array elements never escape the function.  In any case, programmer can make optimizers job easier by adding the `static` keyword, if the array is local.

Answer (score 2):

Any good compiler will convert the initializers during compile time.  However, you also asked

> am I incurring conversion cpu cycles when I perform operations on the array contents?

and that depends on the code performing the operations.  If your expression combines array elements with variables of `double` type, then the operation will be performed at double precision, and the array elements will be promoted (converted) before the arithmetic takes place.

If you just combine array elements with variables of `float` type (including other array elements), then the operation is performed on floats and the language doesn't require any promotion (But if your hardware only implements double precision operations, conversion might still be done.  Such hardware surely makes the conversions very cheap, though.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using float for the rest of the operations, so my question was mainly if I could "get away" with not modifying the enormous array (not all shown here). But I understand what you're saying and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ben Voigt answer addresses your question for most parts.
But you also ask:

On a related note, how many trailing decimal places should a float be able to store

It depends on the value of the number you are trying to store. For large numbers there is no decimals - in fact the format can't even give you a precise value for the integer part. For instance:

```
float x = BIG_NUMBER;
float y = x + 1;
if (x == y)
{
    // The code get here if BIG_NUMBER is very high!
}
else
{
    // The code get here if BIG_NUMBER is no so high!
}
```

If BIG_NUMBER is 2^23 the next greater number would be (2^23 + 1).

If BIG_NUMBER is 2^24 the next greater number would be (2^24 + 2).

The value (2^24 + 1) can not be stored.

For very small numbers (i.e. close to zero), you will have a lot of decimal places.

Floating point is to be used with great care because they are very imprecise.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

For small numbers you can experiment with the program below.

Change the exp variable to set the starting point. The program will show you what the step size is for the range and the first four valid numbers.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int exp = -27; // <---  !!!!!!!!!!!
                   // Change this to set starting point for the range
                   // Starting point will be 2 ^ exp

    float f;
    unsigned int *d = (unsigned int *)&f; // Brute force to set f in binary format
    unsigned int e;


    cout.precision(100);

    // Calculate step size for this range
    e = ((127-23) + exp) << 23;
    *d = e;
    cout << "Step size  = " << fixed << f << endl;
    cout << "First 4 numbers in range:" << endl;

    // Calculate first four valid numbers in this range
    e = (127 + exp) << 23;

    *d = e | 0x00000000;
    cout << hex << "0x" << *d << " = " << fixed << f << endl;

    *d = e | 0x00000001;
    cout << hex << "0x" << *d << " = " << fixed << f << endl;

    *d = e | 0x00000002;
    cout << hex << "0x" << *d << " = " << fixed << f << endl;

    *d = e | 0x00000003;
    cout << hex << "0x" << *d << " = " << fixed << f << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

For exp = -27 the output will be:

```
Step size  = 0.0000000000000008881784197001252323389053344726562500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
First 4 numbers in range:
0x32000000 = 0.0000000074505805969238281250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0x32000001 = 0.0000000074505814851022478251252323389053344726562500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0x32000002 = 0.0000000074505823732806675252504646778106689453125000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0x32000003 = 0.0000000074505832614590872253756970167160034179687500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Hi @nielsen, so in this case? Where my values are like 0.00000000956897738824125100000000 (32 dec places) ? Where the number in front is zero.